# Button not giving correct output

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, mbed

This is a code that I am using to display average temperature every 120s on a mbed device and show the previous average when the SW2 is pressed.
When I press SW2 button more than once, it doesnt diplay the correct output. Which should be the previous average when pressed one time and average with an "r" when pressed before 10s had passed. If I press the button again too quickly this doesnt provide the needed output which is specified above.

Appreciate some guidance on why this happens and how to correct it. Thanks in advance.

Also does this program seems bad design/logic that it doesnt do what it is supposed to?

```
#include "mbed.h"
//LM75B.h package used to obtain
//temperature readings
#include "LM75B.h"
//C12832.h package used to display
//readings on LCD
#include "C12832.h"
//temperature sensor
static LM75B temperature(D14,D15);
//display
static C12832 lcd(D11, D13, D12, D7, D10);
//Button SW2 as a interrupt
InterruptIn sw(SW2);
//Ticker object to run a function at intervals
Ticker ticker;
Ticker ticker2;
//Timer to keep track of time in seconds
Timer timer;
//volatile variable to help with ticker
volatile int actionThis=0;
//variable to check if button
//was already pressed
int pressed=0;
//assign initial temperature values
float avgTemp=temperature.temp();

float tempNow=temperature.temp();
//how often temperature should be taken
#define TEMP_FREQUENCY                  10//in seconds
//how many times temperature should be taken
// to get average
#define AVG_TEMP_AFTER_N_TEMPS          12


//function to initialise temperature taking to calculate
//average temperature
void somethinghappened(void)
{

    actionThis=2;

}

//second function to resolve issue
//of ticker not detaching and attaching correctly 
void somethinghappened2(void)
{

    actionThis=2;

}


//function to display temperature
//at button press
void theTemp(void)
{

//check if a temperature reading
//was taken
    if((timer.read()<TEMP_FREQUENCY)&& pressed) {
        pressed=0;
//position output on screen
        lcd.locate(0,3);
//display laterst average temperature again
        lcd.printf("%.2f%c\n", avgTemp,'r');
        wait(3);
        lcd.cls();
//stop current ticker
        ticker.detach();
//start ticker2 with different frequency
//to resolve problem of ticker not correctly detaching 
//and re attching to same function
        ticker.attach(somethinghappened2,(TEMP_FREQUENCY+1));
    } else {
        pressed=1;
        lcd.locate(0,3);
        lcd.printf("%.2f\n", avgTemp);
        wait(3);
//clear the screen
        lcd.cls();
//reset timer to 0
        timer.reset();
        ticker.detach();
        ticker.attach(somethinghappened2,(TEMP_FREQUENCY+1));
    }
}


//function to get temperature at a regular
//interval and display average after certain
//time has passed
void calcAvg(void)
{
    int x;
    tempNow=0;

//loop to display average temperature after
//certain time period
    for( x=1; x<(AVG_TEMP_AFTER_N_TEMPS+1); x++) {

        tempNow=tempNow+temperature.temp();

        if(x==AVG_TEMP_AFTER_N_TEMPS) {
            timer.stop();
            avgTemp=tempNow/x;

            lcd.locate(0,3);
            lcd.printf("%.2f\n", avgTemp);
            wait(3);
            lcd.cls();

            break;
        }
//sleep until called by ticker
        sleep();
    }
}


int main (void)
{
//timer to track time passed
        timer.start();
//run function at button press
    sw.rise(&theTemp);
    ticker.attach(somethinghappened,TEMP_FREQUENCY);
//run infinitely
    while(1) {
        if(actionThis==2) {
            actionThis=0;
            calcAvg();
        }
//sleep till called 
        sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pick _one_ language, unless your question is specifically about interoperability between multiple programs written in different languages.  This looks like C++.  Please explain why Java and C are mentioned in the tags (this will cause your question to appear in searches for those languages).

Comment: Hi, paddy yes this is C++. I thought since  all these languages are mostly simillar that I would put both java and c.

Comment: This code will not compile as C or Java.  When you tag as C or Java, you attract C or Java experts who will be looking to offer their expertise in those languages to your problem.  By your assertion that the languages are "mostly similar", there is a much higher chance you will waste their time, or potentially attract low-quality answers in the case where someone _thinks_ they understand a language based on what they know about another.